# Amazon Cognito: an error occur while trying logout

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, incognito-mode, amazon-cognito-facebook, amazon-cognito-triggers

this the request uri

```
https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/?response_type=code&client_id=<client_id>' + '&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/'
```

it redirect to this uri with error that chown in image

```
https://mydomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/error?error=redirect_mismatch&client_id=<client_id>
```

[image]

Note that: everything works fine with login

Answer (score 1):

Please try below URLs

Cognito Setting:
Cognito User Pool --> "Sign in and sign out URLs" → "Callback URL(s)" →

Value to be added  :
",https://localhost/dashboard,https://localhost/oauth2/idpresponse,"

If this does not work then try adding port as well.

Answer (score 0):

you are redirect to localhost, it's not url valid because is not public on internet

Comment: I tried to use https://www.google.com/ instead of  http://localhost:8080/ but the same error occured

Comment: you configure the application client??

Comment: Login and logout URLs
Please enter the callback URLs below that you will include in login and logout requests. Each field can include multiple URLs, separated by commas.